# Fechar aba do Mozilla, IE, Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando fechar uma aba do meu site, já tentei usar os seguintes comandos:

- `window.open('','_self',''); window.close();`
- `window.close()`
- `self.close()`
- `var win = window.open("","_self"); win.close();`
- `window.parent.close();`
- `window.top.close()`
- `top.open('','_self',''); top.close();`

Muitos desses funcionam certo no Chrome e no IE, só que no Mozilla não funciona, apenas funciona se for executado o comando no console em uma nova aba, mas não na aba do meu site.

Alguém tem alguma dica?

Comment: Desde a versão 27 do Firefox, a segurança com o fechamento de abas aumentou, portanto até mesmo os hacks utilizados nas versões <27 deixaram de funcionar.

Comment: que pena, eu realmente precisava fechar essa aba. Obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 3):

Olá, para executar o window.close() o action deve vir a partir de um evento ( costumo usar sempre o click ), pois não sei se funciona para outros eventos.

Portanto, se você fizer:

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function()
{
    window.close();
}, false);
```

A aba será fechada, isto é válido para abas do seu site, no caso de popup não há esse problema, desde que o popup foi aberto a partir do seu site!
Exemplo em popup:

```
var popup = window.open("http://www.teste.com.br");
popup.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Tente fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
function tabClose() {
  var tab = window.open("","_self");
  tab.close();
}
```

Não utilizo IE, mas no Chrome e Firefox, resolve o seu problema, talvez no IE também, mas não consegui testar.

Answer (score 2):

Assim funcionou no chrome e IE.
As opções "_blank" e "_self" não resolvem, use "_top".
Somente a aba aberta será fechada, se for a última aba o navegador fecha!

```
function tabClose() {
  var tab = window.open(window.location,"_top");
  tab.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Encontrei o mesmo problema e resolvi usando:

```
window.frames.closewindow();
```

Isto porque trabalho com um sistema baseado em frames, não fiz o teste com outro tipo de sistema.
Vale a pena tentar.