# Comando Javascript para encerrar janela do navegador

Tags: javascript

Existe um comando que pode ser usado em um Javascript que encerra o processo do navegador em que o mesmo está rodando?

Comment: Encerrar oq exatamente?

Comment: A aba, a aplicação. O processo...

Comment: Aqui já tem respostas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17401/8063